# How to define CustomAPI to use on-premise Gateway in bicep

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I try to automatically deploy a Custom API and Logic apps custom connector with are using an on-premise Data Gateway for use in Logic Apps.

I getting following Error: {"code":"ManagedApiNotRegisteredForOnPremise","message":"The managed API 'XXX_V2' is not registered for on-premise and hence cannot be used for creating on-premise connection."

```bicep
var swagger = loadJsonContent('../XXX_v2_swagger.json')

resource customApi 'Microsoft.Web/customApis@2016-06-01' = {
  name: customApiName
  location: location
  tags: union(tags, { 'azd-service-name': customApiName })
  properties: {
    connectionParameters: {
      authType: {
        type: 'string'
      }
      gateway: {
        type: 'gatewaySetting'
      }
    }
    capabilities: [
      'gateway'
    ]
    description: '${customApiName} REST API for on-prem Connection'
    displayName: customApiName
    iconUri: 'https://content.powerapps.com/resource/makerx/static/media/default-connection-icon.00d06b6e.svg'
    apiType: 'Rest'
    swagger: swagger
    backendService: {
      serviceUrl: 'https://mylocalendpoint.com'
    }
  }
}

resource connection 'Microsoft.Web/connections@2016-06-01' = {
  name: connectionName
  location: location
//  kind: 'V2' // doesn't work with bicep
  tags: union(tags, { 'azd-service-name': connectionName })
  properties: {
    displayName: '${connectionName}API-Services Gateway'
    statuses: [
      {
        status: 'Connected'
      }
    ]
    parameterValues: {
      authType: 'anonymous'
      gateway: {
        name: gatewayName
        id: connectionGatewayExternalId
        type: 'Microsoft.Web/connectionGateways'
      }
    }
    api: {
      name: connectionName
      displayName: connectionName
      description: '${connectionName} REST API for on-prem Connection'
      iconUri: 'https://content.powerapps.com/resource/makerx/static/media/default-connection-icon.00d06b6e.svg'
      id: customApi.id
      type: 'Microsoft.Web/customApis'
    }
  }
}
```

I manually created everything in Azure Portal, exported template and reused except the apiDefinitions (because i need to update with the swagger file) and the gateways settings need to be in `parameterValues` instead of `nonSecretParametersValues` otherwise the gateway will be empty. [See Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74215773/561424)

I saw, that the `capabilities: [ 'gateway' ]` needs to be set and is also set in the Custom connector in the Azure Portal: [image: set gateway]

Comment: Did you manage to get that working ?

Comment: no, still no success.

Comment: The error shows that it is not connected to on premises to access. Have you connected it to on premise properly? @pocki_c

Comment: I try to connect through the Connection with the parameters gateway. It's the On-Prem Data Gateway On-Prem installed and in Azure configured as Data Gateway. 
I can manually create the Connection and select the Data Gateway. This is also working. But I can't create the connection with the Gateway in the parameters in bicep (error). and as nonSecretParameters (like the downloaded Template) nothing is entered in the connection